# Microsoft DNS Server, is it possible to make it use default domain suffix?

Tags: networking, dns

Is it possible to setup Microsoft DNS server to return the IP address of "TheHost.TheDomain", when the client only asked for "TheHost"?

Windows has domain suffix feature so that ".TheDomain" seems to be automatically added even if the user typed "TheHost". But on Android, there seems to be no such feature, so "TheHost" is not resolved and the user has to type "TheHost.TheDomain". If the DNS server treats "TheHost" as "TheHost.TheDomain" automatically, this should be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

That's the short answer.  DNS **servers** only deal with fully-qualified domain names (FQDN), so if you ask it for the A record for "TheHost", then it will look it up as if it was a top-level domain, which doesn't exist.

What you're after is search suffix lists so the client can append domains to single-label host names and try them as FQDNs, which can be set via a Global Policy object, or handed out via DHCP in a search-list option (119).

The latter *should* be honored by Android devices, at least, I don't have any problem with my Android devices when handing out option 119 (search-list) and option 15 (domain-name) via DHCP.